# How to configure springdoc ui without mapping the root path?

Tags: java, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm trying to configure springdoc-openapi-ui in a spring web app (non-springboot). In my application I have a controller that is mapped to "/" which conflicts with the Springdoc SwaggerUiHome Controller.  I get an error similar to this:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'swaggerUiHome' method 'org.springdoc.webmvc.ui.SwaggerUiHome#index() to {GET [/]}: There is already 'loginLogoutController' bean method com.company.MyController#method() mapped.

If I disable my controller which is mapped to '/' then the swagger UI comes up as expected. However, I need to have my controller running in order for my web app to work.
Even if I set 'springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=false' (which should be the default anyway) it is still causing an ambiguous mapping error.

Is there any way around this?  Any way to disable the default mapping of the SwaggerUiHome.index() to '/'?

Comment: Can you share the exact config that you have for Springdoc? Including the beans you might have declared to integrate Springdoc

Answer (score 2):

SwaggerUiHome is only invoked if you define: `springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true`

To disable it: `springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=false`

Note that default path of the swagger-ui is not the root path, but: `http://server:port/context-path/swagger-ui.html`

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error if using regular spring framework (not using spring-boot). After dig into the source `/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui-2.0.2.jar/org.springdoc.webmvc.ui/SwaggerConfig.class`

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = SPRINGDOC_USE_ROOT_PATH, havingValue = "true")
@Lazy(false)
SwaggerUiHome swaggerUiHome() {
    return new SwaggerUiHome();
}
```

Found that `String SPRINGDOC_USE_ROOT_PATH = "springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path"`. I guess there maybe a bug that this property is not working for `springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=false`

Here is my working solution after reading https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping#4-ambiguous-mapping-error

```
@GetMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String index() {
    return "home";
}
```